# Не могу решить задачу: нужно найти "счастливый номер билета" из целых чисел

Tags: java

Написал вот это, но компилятор постоянно ругается. Подскажите начинающему, что я не так делаю.
Суть задачи: найти число, которое является счастливым билетом

```
public class LuckyTicket {
int luckynumber;
    go(){
        for (int x = 0; x >=100; x++){
        if (x == luckynumber){
        return f;
        }
    }
}
public static void main (String [] args){
    LuckyTicket check = new LuckyTicket;

    check.go();
    System.out.println("Выиграшный билет находится под числом:" + f);

    }
}
```

Comment: "но компилятор постоянно ругается" - какими словами?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите серйозно заниматься программированием, то лучше почитайте [вот это](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). У Вас нету понимания основных концепций программирования и, поэтому, писать программы Вам еще рановато. Вот Вам моя реализация вашей задачи и пример ее использования.

---

P.S. Я предполагаю, что счастливый билет - это билет у которого сумма первых трех чисел совпадает с суммой последних трех.

```
public class Ticket {
    private int[] nums;

    public Ticket(int... nums){
        if(nums.length != 6)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.nums = Arrays.copyOf(nums, nums.length);
    }

    public boolean isLucky() {
        return (nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2]) ==
               (nums[3] + nums[4] + nums[5]);
    }

}
```

Как этим можно пользоваться:

```
    int[] ticket1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1};
    int[] ticket2 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int[] ticket3 = new int[]{1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    //Ticket t3 = new Ticket(ticket3); This will cause an error!

    Ticket t1 = new Ticket(ticket1);
    if(t1.isLucky())
        System.out.println("Yeah!!! This ticket is lucky :)");

    Ticket t2 = new Ticket(ticket2);
    if(!t2.isLucky())
        System.out.println("Oh no :(");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private int luckynumber;

    private Integer go() {
        for (int x = 0; x >= 100; x++) {
            if (x == luckynumber) return x;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LuckyTicket check = new LuckyTicket();
        Integer result = check.go();
        System.out.println("Выиграшный билет находится под числом:" + result);

    }

}
```

Так не будет ругаться... просто это программа ничего не делает, всегда результат будет 0, потому как переменная luckynumber по умолчанию равна 0. А какого функционала вы пытались добиться одному Богу известно...

Comment: она даже в цикл не зайдет

Comment: понятное дело, но вопрос состоит в том, что компилятор ругается. сделал тоже самое, чтобы не ругался. а цель всего этого громадного приложения нигде автором вопроса не написана, а я не экстрасенс...